# Google Scripts, calling isRequired and setRequired on multipleChoiceItem fails

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I'm working on a piece of C#-code that maintains a questionnaire on Forms and keeps it in sync with a local database, e.g. when users use the program they simultaneously change data on Forms and in the database.

Since there is no Forms-API I'm using Google Scripts with a couple of helper methods as an inbetween to perform the changes on Forms.

One of the options of the program is to change existing questions, and specifically whether a question is required to be answered. I use the following code:

```js
var questionItem = listOfItems[startOfSection + 1];

var currQues = questionItem.getTitle();
if(currQues !== questionString) {      
  Logger.log('Changed questionString from ' + currQues + ' to ' + questionString);
  questionItem.setTitle(questionString);
}

var currReq = questionItem.isRequired();
if(currReq !== isQuestionRequired) {
  questionItem.setRequired(isQuestionRequired);
}
```

When checking for the type of variable questionItem by calling the getType()-method, it tells me it's a multipleChoiceItem, which has a method called isRequired to read the current bool, and setRequired to set the bool. However, calling both isRequired and setRequired fail, the error message being

```
[Cannot find function isRequired in object Item.]
```

and the error type is

```
[TypeError]
```

Logger shows my questionItem var is a MultipleChoiceItem, so why does my code fail? And why does Scripts return a value to my C#-code saying the method was called on a generic "Item"?

Another method that sets new questions also calls setRequired after creating a MultipleChoiceItem and that one works without a problem.

FYI, startOfSection, questionString and isQuestionRequired are parameters given to the method during the request using the ScriptsService of the C# API.

Comment: It's better that questions about code that isn't working include a [mcve] (actually there is a close reason that says that it's required).

Answer (score 0):

[setRequired](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#setrequiredenabled) requires a Boolean as parameter. The problem is that isQuestionRequired is not a Boolean.

If isQuestionRequired is a string, which value is `'true'`, you could replace

```
questionItem.setRequired(isQuestionRequired)
```

by

```
questionItem.setRequired(isQuestionRequired === 'true');
```

Comment: I use the same parameters for an addSection function on Scripts which works okay. The big difference is that I create a MultipleChoiceItem there to add to a Form, whereas in the code I shared here it is an existing one retrieved from a Form. The thing is that Scripts gives an error saying that the variable I call "questionItem" is not a MultipleChoiceItem but a generic "Item", although logging it's type with the getType() method tells me it IS a MultipleChoiceItem.

Comment: Just made an extra check on the inputs, the isQuestionRequired parameter is received on Google Scripts as a boolean, like I intended. It's not a string, the ScriptsResource RunRequest method of the C# API correctly converts my C#-boolean in the parameterlist to a Google Scripts/Javascript boolean. It seems the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Yuregenu: I'm sorry, I misread the question and understood that the problem was with setRequired instead of isRequired. I will delete this answer later.

Answer (score 0):

```
var questionItem = listOfItems[startOfSection + 1];
```

The above line of code tell us that `questionItem` gets its values from an array. It's very likely that problem is on how the array members were created.

As you already found that the error occurred on an object of "generic item" type, one solution is to use [asMultipleChoiceItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asMultipleChoiceItem()) to make to conversition to the expected type.

Change

```
questionItem.setRequired(isQuestionRequired)
```

to

```
questionItem.asMultipleChoiceItem().setRequired(isQuestionRequired)
```